# text-align center not working for me

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I'm trying to change the text alignment on one specific line of text on a page I am working on and haven't really been too successful. I've tried using div class and div id as well as p class and p id and making modifications in the CSS file, but it doesn't seem to be working for me. I am trying to center the "dedicated to the memory..." line. Here are my HTML and CSS files:

```css
body {
  background-color: #008000;
}

h1 {
  border-style: double;
  font-family: times-new-roman;
  color: white;
}

p {
  color: white;
  font-family: times-new-roman;
}

h2 {
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:link {
  color: blue;
}

a:visited {
  color: purple;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

<p style="text-align:center;">Dedicated to the memory of Rhodesia's special forces operators</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Melander_and_Hupli_RLI_1979_simulation_4_%28cropped%29.jpg" width=300 height=200></p>
<span style=f ont-family="times-new-roman" font-weight="200"><h2>Rhodesian Light Infantry</h2></span>
<p class="regular">The Rhodesian Light Infantry was formed on February 1st, 1961. It was part of the army of the Central African Federation. This unit was Rhodesia's equivalent to the United States' 75th Ranger Regiment When the war against black nationalist guerrillas
  broke out in the 1960s, they played a crucial role in counterterrorism operations. In the latter stages of the conflict, the unit became trained in airborne operations. Throughout the RLI's history, it was an exclusively white unit. Volunteers from
  all throughout the world fought and died in the Rhodesian Light Infantry. In October 1980, the RLI was officially disbanded following the formation of Zimbabwe.</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Selous_Scouts_II.jpg" width=200 height=200></p>
<h2>Selous Scouts</h2>
<p class="regular2">The Selous Scouts were created in 1973 during the Rhodesian Bush War. Their name came from famed hunter Frederick Courtney Selous. Ronald Reid-Daly commanded this notable unit. The Shona phrase <i>Pamwe chete</i> or <q>all together</q> was the Selous
  Scouts' motto. The Selous Scouts have 68% of all enemy deaths during the Rhodesian Bush War to their credit. Like other famed Rhodesian units, the Selous Scouts were disbanded upon the forming of the new government of Zimbabwe.</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/C_Squadron_%28Rhodesian%29_SAS%2C_1953.jpg" width=400 height=200></p>
<h2>Rhodesian Special Air Service</h2>
<p class="regular3">The history of the Rhodesian Special Air Service goes back to the Malayan Emergency. <q>C</q> Squadron of the SAS was made up of volunteers from Southern Rhodesia. Once this unit had completed their tour of duty in Malaya, they were disbanded. The Rhodesian
  Special Air Service was reactivated in the 1960s and fought during the insurgency against African nationalist forces. Upon Robert Mugabe's ascension to the Zimbabwean presidency in 1980, the Rhodesian SAS was disbanded permanently.</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work, see the snippet.

```html
<h1>Special Forces of Rhodesia</h1>
<p style="text-align:center;">Dedicated to the memory of Rhodesia's special forces operators</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Melander_and_Hupli_RLI_1979_simulation_4_%28cropped%29.jpg" 
width=300 height=200></p>
<span style= font-family="times-new-roman" font-weight="200"><h2>Rhodesian Light Infantry</h2></span>
<p class="regular">The Rhodesian Light Infantry was formed on February 1st, 1961. It was part of the army of the Central African
Federation. This unit was Rhodesia's equivalent to the United States' 75th Ranger Regiment When the war against black 
nationalist guerrillas broke out in the 1960s, they played a crucial role in counterterrorism operations. 
In the latter stages of the conflict, the unit became trained in airborne operations. Throughout the RLI's history, it
was an exclusively white unit. Volunteers from all throughout the world fought and died in the Rhodesian Light Infantry.
In October 1980, the RLI was officially disbanded following the formation of Zimbabwe.</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Selous_Scouts_II.jpg" width=200 height=200></p>
<h2>Selous Scouts</h2>
<p class="regular2">The Selous Scouts were created in 1973 during the Rhodesian Bush War. Their name came from famed hunter
Frederick Courtney Selous. Ronald Reid-Daly commanded this notable unit. The Shona phrase <i>Pamwe chete</i> or <q>all together</q>
was the Selous Scouts' motto. The Selous Scouts have 68% of all enemy deaths during the Rhodesian Bush War to their credit.
Like other famed Rhodesian units, the Selous Scouts were disbanded upon the forming of the new government of Zimbabwe.</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/C_Squadron_%28Rhodesian%29_SAS%2C_1953.jpg" width=400
height=200></p>
<h2>Rhodesian Special Air Service</h2>
    <p class="regular3">The history of the Rhodesian Special Air Service goes back to the Malayan Emergency. <q>C</q> Squadron of the SAS was
made up of volunteers from Southern Rhodesia. Once this unit had completed their tour of duty in Malaya, they were disbanded.
The Rhodesian Special Air Service was reactivated in the 1960s and fought during the insurgency against African nationalist
    forces. Upon Robert Mugabe's ascension to the Zimbabwean presidency in 1980, the Rhodesian SAS was disbanded permanently.</p>
```

Comment: That's good that it works here, but it doesn't show up when it opens in Microsoft Edge.

Answer (score 0):

It works with an ID in CSS, but it should already run. There is an open style tag, close or remove it. Your inline CSS is invalid.

```html
<span style= font-family="times-new-roman" font-weight="200">

<span style="font-family: times-new-roman" font-weight="200">
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<style>
body
{
background-color:#008000;
}
h1{
border-style:double;
font-family:times-new-roman;
color:white;
}
p{
color: white;
font-family:times-new-roman;
}
h2{
color:#ffffff;
}
a:link{
color:blue;
}
a:visited{
color:purple;
}
#centerTitle{
 text-align: center;
}
</style>
<title>My first web page</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Special Forces of Rhodesia</h1>
<p id="centerTitle">Dedicated to the memory of Rhodesia's special forces operators</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/77/Melander_and_Hupli_RLI_1979_simulation_4_%28cropped%29.jpg" 
width=300 height=200></p>
<span style="font-family: times-new-roman" font-weight="200"><h2>Rhodesian Light Infantry</h2></span>
<p class="regular">The Rhodesian Light Infantry was formed on February 1st, 1961. It was part of the army of the Central African
Federation. This unit was Rhodesia's equivalent to the United States' 75th Ranger Regiment When the war against black 
nationalist guerrillas broke out in the 1960s, they played a crucial role in counterterrorism operations. 
In the latter stages of the conflict, the unit became trained in airborne operations. Throughout the RLI's history, it
was an exclusively white unit. Volunteers from all throughout the world fought and died in the Rhodesian Light Infantry.
In October 1980, the RLI was officially disbanded following the formation of Zimbabwe.</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b6/Selous_Scouts_II.jpg" width=200 height=200></p>
<h2>Selous Scouts</h2>
<p class="regular2">The Selous Scouts were created in 1973 during the Rhodesian Bush War. Their name came from famed hunter
Frederick Courtney Selous. Ronald Reid-Daly commanded this notable unit. The Shona phrase <i>Pamwe chete</i> or <q>all together</q>
was the Selous Scouts' motto. The Selous Scouts have 68% of all enemy deaths during the Rhodesian Bush War to their credit.
Like other famed Rhodesian units, the Selous Scouts were disbanded upon the forming of the new government of Zimbabwe.</p>
<br>
<br>
<p><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2e/C_Squadron_%28Rhodesian%29_SAS%2C_1953.jpg" width=400
height=200></p>
<h2>Rhodesian Special Air Service</h2>
    <p class="regular3">The history of the Rhodesian Special Air Service goes back to the Malayan Emergency. <q>C</q> Squadron of the SAS was
made up of volunteers from Southern Rhodesia. Once this unit had completed their tour of duty in Malaya, they were disbanded.
The Rhodesian Special Air Service was reactivated in the 1960s and fought during the insurgency against African nationalist
    forces. Upon Robert Mugabe's ascension to the Zimbabwean presidency in 1980, the Rhodesian SAS was disbanded permanently.</p>
 </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some invalid syntax.  There is an open style tag in the head. 
Remove the style tag or close it.

There is also an inline style issue after the p.

```
<span style= font-family="times-new-roman" font-weight="200">
```

Should be

```
<span style="font-family: times-new-roman" font-weight="200">
```

Works in Chrome and Edge